# Getting complete response from database with Backbone.js

Tags: javascript, json, django, backbone.js

I have a response from my Django API to my Backbone.js frontend and I am only receiving part of my data.

The response I am receiving looks like this:

```
{"count":27,"next":"http://127.0.0.1:8000/messages/?page=2","previous":null,"results":    
   [
     {"url":"http://127.0.0.1:8000/messages/1/","creator":"CREATOR","content":"CONTENT","post_date":"2015-04-21T22:13:08.654152Z"},
     {"url":"http://127.0.0.1:8000/messages/2/","creator":"CREATOR2","content":"CONTENT2","post_date":"2015-04-21T22:13:08.654152Z"},
     ...
   ]
}
```

This is because my reponse has a `next` field with a URL to the rest of the response. How should I handle this in Backbone in order to get the entire response from the server?

**Here is the `sync` function from my collection:

```
sync: function(method, model, options) {
  var that = this;
  var params = _.extend({
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    url: that.url,
    processData: false
  }, options);
  return $.ajax(params);
}
```

So it just makes a `GET` request to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/messages/`, but I do not know how to make another request to the `next` response parameter.

Comment: So, are you making server request from Backbone like `http://127.0.0.1:8000/messages/?page=1` ?

Comment: To clarify, is Django outputting the correct information? It also may be worth showing us some more of your backbone code.

Comment: @VigneswaranMarimuthu well I adjusted the `collection`'s `sync` function, I'll show you how it looks in my edited question. On a basic level, it just makes a `GET` request to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/messages/`.

Comment: @KristianRoebuck yes the response is correct, I just don't know how to make a second response to the url from the `next` part of the response.

Comment: @Zach And check what's the output from Django ?

Comment: So, are you trying to do pagination ? With Backbone ?

Comment: @VigneswaranMarimuthu from the `GET` request to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/messages/` I receive the response I got in the question. The problem is the response has a `next` piece that I don't know how to handle. I know I need to make a `GET` response to it, but I'm not sure how I should do that in Backbone, and which function to override in the collection

Comment: @VigneswaranMarimuthu I believe so. I don't want my front end to be paginated, but I guess the response from my API is paginated, so I want to be able to grab every page from it.

Comment: Check out this one if this might be of any help - https://github.com/backbone-paginator/backbone.paginator

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75929/discussion-between-zach-and-vigneswaran-marimuthu).

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem in my `settings.py` filed in the Django app. I'm using Django Rest Framework and there is a config options to set the pagination size, so I made it huge.